# HTML / PHP - Textarea shows tabs / spaces from code

Tags: php, html, textarea, form-fields

For readability reasons , I have a code that looks like this :

```
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5"  id="k99_brsa_settings[brsa_keep_settings_exp]"  name="k99_brsa_settings[brsa_keep_settings_exp]" />
            <?php echo $export; ?>
        </textarea>
```

I do not know how to represent / display `tabs` here , but it is actually like so :

```
[TAB][TAB][TAB][TAB]<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="k99_brsa_settings[brsa_keep_settings_exp]"  name="k99_brsa_settings[brsa_keep_settings_exp]" />
[TAB][TAB][TAB][TAB][TAB]<?php echo $export; ?>
[TAB][TAB][TAB][TAB]</textarea>
```

or better yet with an image ( code editor ) :

[image: Code tabs in editor]

The problem is , that those tabs appear in the Output like so :

[image: Tabs appear in textarea]

and since those are DB entries, when I save , it actually CHANGES the entry (adds tabs and spaces )

I know that when I change the code to a `one liner`:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5"  id="k99_brsa_settings[brsa_keep_settings_exp]" name="k99_brsa_settings[brsa_keep_settings_exp]" /><?php echo $export; ?></textarea>
```

(image from code editor below )

[image: Image with one liner]

...there is no problem and no tabs / spaces .

Is there any way to keep the tabs for readability AND eliminating those output tabs and spaces ? Does the `<textarea>` TAGS always HAVE to end after the output without spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still keep it on multiple lines with

```
<textarea ...><?php

?></textarea>
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
<?php
    echo "<textarea line1>"
        . $export
        . "</textarea>";
?>
```

Comment: Extending the PHP tags a nice solution, although it does damage the readability a bit - thanks. It is very strange to me because I never had such a problem with other tags ..

Comment: Most html is rather white-space agnostic, even text doesn't keep more then a single space without additional work or a `<pre></pre>` tag, but textareas could have tabs in them, and some stuff I've worked with all but requires support for tabs, so the browsers put all that in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and trim extra whitespaces down to a single whitespace I guess. Or change your markup to remove the tabs.

```
<?php
    // This will replace any double whitespace with a single whitespace
    $result = str_replace('  ', ' ', $result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to shorten your php a little by replacing `<?php echo $export; ?>` with `<?= $export ?>`.  It may make you feel better about putting it all on one line.

I know people don't suggest the use of shorttags, but per http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php, the  short tag syntax will always be recognized by php 5.4 and up.